# Use of notwithstanding in start of a sentence

Tags: conjunctions

I had wondered over the usage of notwithstanding for a long time when I got this problem. 
I came out with a few solutions.But, I don't know which one is right or wrong.

### Maya worked very hard but did not impress her teacher. (Begin with Notwithstanding)

> 1. Notwithstanding her hard work, Maya did not impress her teacher.
> 2. Notwithstanding Maya worked very hard, she did not impress her teacher.
> 3. Notwithstanding the fact that Maya worked very hard, she did not impress her teacher.
> 4. Notwithstanding Maya's hard work, she did not impress her teacher.
> 5. Notwithstanding that Maya worked very hard, she did not impress her teacher.

Can you tell me which one of the sentences is correct? And the reason for the one being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would accept 1, 3, and 4, and probably 5. Not 2.

I think 1 is the most natural.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* these are correct.